# How to copy and paste a range under A1: A8 using a common identifier that is repeated at the beginning of 8 column data sets across a row

Tags: excel, vba

Example data set

```
A      B     c      D     E     F    G       H         I     J     K      L    M     N      O    P
-10    5     16     23    8     2    6       3162625  -10    5     16     23   8     2      6    3162626
```

Desired output

```
A      B     C      D     E     F    G       H         I     J     K      L    M     N      O    P
-10    5     16     23    8     2    6       3162625 
-10    5     16     23    8     2    6       3162626
```

Constant is -10 and i need the 7 columns after it

using VBA I can transfer column A to H to another sheet, but i can't get the VBA to move to Column I, Q etc etc

The VBA I have is

```
Sub search_and_extract_singlecriteria()
'1.
'2.
'3.

Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
Dim recordid As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set datasheet = Sheet1
Set reportsheet = Sheet2
recordid = "-46" 'reportsheet.Range("B2").Value

'reportsheet.Range("A1:L100").ClearContents

datasheet.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = recordid Then
        Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 17)).Copy
        reportsheet.Select
        Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        datasheet.Select
        End If
Next i

reportsheet.Select

Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

Simple copy and paste is not an option as on one row, the 8 column sets repeat  over a 1000 columns. each row, has varying column lengths.  i will end up with 300k plus rows across 8 columns A:H if this can be done
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Have added some comments to explain.

If it's slow, more efficient to use arrays.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

application.screenupdating=false

Set r = Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(, 8) 'set starting range 1 x 8

Do Until IsEmpty(r(1)) 'keep doing this until first cell is empty
    r.Copy Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) 'copy to first blank cell in A sheet2
    Set r = r.Offset(, 8) 'move copy range along by 8 cells to the right
Loop

application.screenupdating=true

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Perhaps you'd be so kind as to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

### Array vs Range

```vb
Option Explicit

'START ****************************************************************** START'
' Title:        Search and Extract Single Criteria                             '
' Purpose:      In a specified Data Worksheet, each non-empty row contains     '
'               an unknown number of consecutive data sets of a specified      '
'               size (columns).                                                '
'               By looping through each row of Data Worksheet, copies each     '
'               data set to another specified Report Worksheet one below       '
'               another, starting from a specified cell range.                 '
'******************************************************************************'
Sub search_and_extract_singlecriteria()
' 10s for 1280 cols and 3000 rows = 480000 rows in Report Sheet

    Const Noc As Long = 8         ' Size of Data Set (Number of Columns)
                                  ' = Number of Columns in Report Array
    Const strRR As String = "B2"  ' Report First Cell Range Address

    Dim wsD As Worksheet: Set wsD = Sheet1  ' Data Sheet
    Dim wsR As Worksheet: Set wsR = Sheet2  ' Report Sheet

    Dim rng As Range           ' Last Non-Empty Cell in the Last Non-Empty Row,
                               ' Non-Empty Range (both in Data Sheet)
    Dim vntD As Variant        ' Data Array (2D 1-based)
    Dim vntC As Variant        ' Count Array (1D 1-based)
    Dim vntR As Variant        ' Report Array (2D 1-based)
    Dim Nor As Long            ' Number of Data Sets
                               ' = Number of Rows in Report Array
    Dim i As Long              ' Data/Count Array Rows Counter
    Dim j As Long              ' Data Array Columns Counter
    Dim k As Long              ' Count Array Values Counter
    Dim m As Long              ' Report Array Rows Counter

    ' IN DATA SHEET

    ' Note: It is assumed that Data Sheet contains ONLY Data Sets.

    ' By defining the Last Non-Empty Cell in the Last Non-Empty Row
    ' using the Find method, check if the sheet is not empty.
    Set rng = wsD.Cells.Find("*", wsD.Cells(wsD.Rows.Count, wsD.Columns.Count), _
      xlFormulas, , xlByRows)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Define Non-Empty Range on Data Sheet.
    Set rng = wsD.Range(wsD.Cells(rng.Row, wsD.Cells.Find("*", _
      wsD.Cells(wsD.Rows.Count, wsD.Columns.Count), , , xlByColumns).Column), _
      wsD.Cells(wsD.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row, _
      wsD.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column))

    ' Write values of Non-Empty Range on Data Sheet to Data Array.
    vntD = rng

    ' Release object variables. Necessary data is in Data Array (vntD).
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set wsD = Nothing

    ' IN ARRAYS

    ' Task: Calculate Number of Rows in Report Array and populate Count Array.

    ' Resize Count Array (vntC) to number of rows of Data Array (vntD).
    ReDim vntC(1 To UBound(vntD))
    ' Loop through rows (1st dimension) of Data Array (vntD).
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntD)
        ' Loop through every Noc-th column (2nd dimension) of Data Array (vntD).
        For j = 1 To UBound(vntD, 2) Step Noc
            ' Check if value of current element in Data Array (vntD) is <> "".
            If vntD(i, j) <> "" Then
            ' Value of current element in Data Array (vntD) is <> "".
                ' Increase Count Array Value (Count of Data Sets in current row
                ' of Data Array).
                k = k + 1
                ' Increase Number of Rows in Report Array
                ' (Total Count of Data Sets).
                Nor = Nor + 1
            Else
            ' Value of current element in Data Array (vntD) is = "".
                ' The following will leave the current element in Count Array
                ' empty, i.e. 0 which becomes obvious only later in:
                ' "If vntC(i) > 0 Then...".
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        ' Write current Count Array Value (k) to current element
        ' of Count Array (vntC).
        ' Note: The i-th row in Data Array contains k Data Sets.
        vntC(i) = k
        ' Reset Count Array Values Counter.
        k = 0
    Next
    ' Remarks: Count Array (vntC) has the same number of elemnts
    '          as Data Array (vntD) has rows. Each value in Count Array (vntC)
    '          respresents the number of Data Sets per row of Data Array (vntD).
    '          The implementation of Count Array (vntC) makes it possible
    '          to write the last loop as a For Next loop:
    '          "For j = (k - 1) * Noc + 1 To (k - 1) * Noc + Noc...",
    '          without checking if there are "" values, because it has
    '          already been checked previously in:
    '          "If vntD(i, j) <> "" Then)...".

    ' Task: Define and populate Report Array.

    ' Resize Report Array (vntR) to rows defined by Number of Data Sets (Nor)
    ' and columns specified by (Column) Size of Data Set (Noc).
    ReDim vntR(1 To Nor, 1 To Noc)
    ' Loop through rows (1st dimension) of Data Array (vntD).
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntD)
        ' Check if the value in the same row (i) in Count Array (vntC) is > 0.
        If vntC(i) > 0 Then
        ' Value in the same row (i) in Count Array (vntC) is > 0.
            ' Loop through Data Sets from Data Array.
            For k = 1 To vntC(i)
                ' Increase Report Array Rows Counter (m).
                m = m + 1
                ' Loop through columns (j) of current Data Set.
                For j = (k - 1) * Noc + 1 To (k - 1) * Noc + Noc
                    ' Write value of current element of Data Array (Set) to
                    ' current element of Report Array.
                    vntR(m, j - (k - 1) * Noc) = vntD(i, j)
                Next
            Next
        'Else
        ' Value in the same row (i) in Count Array (vntC) is NOT > 0 i.e.
        ' skipping (No Data Set in) current row of Data Array (vntD).
        End If
    Next

    ' IN REPORT SHEET

    ' Copy values of Report Array to Report Range defined by the specified
    ' Report First Cell Range Address (strRR) in specified Report Sheet (wsR)
    ' and the size (rows and columns) of Report Array (vntR).
    wsR.Range(strRR).Resize(UBound(vntR), UBound(vntR, 2)) = vntR

End Sub
'END ********************************************************************** END'
```

Comment: In will try the array answer today.  Thanks again to those who took time to read and answer my problem.